# Swift-SceneKit-Can not load '.scn' file from 'art.scnassets'

Tags: swift, scenekit, scnscene

I'm trying to create a new `SCNScene` from 'diceCollada.scn' file.
But this file won't be loaded.
[image]

This file is in "ARDicee/art.assets" folder.

Not only "diceCollada.scn", but also it cannot load the default "ship.scn".
I don't know why it doesn't load files.

---

Here is my code.

```swift
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Set the view's delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self
        
        // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
         
        // Create a new scene. ---------- The error is here ---------------
        guard let diceScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/diceCollada.scn") else {
            fatalError()
        }
        // Setting node
        if let diceNode = diceScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Dice", recursively: true) {
            diceNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -0.1)
            sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(diceNode)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.isSupported {
            
            // Create a session configuration
            let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

            // Run the view's session
            sceneView.session.run(configuration)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        
        // Pause the view's session
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }
}
```

---

Xcode - Version 14.1

macOS Ventura - Version 13.0.1

GitHub - [This project](https://github.com/AdamYoneda/ARDicee)

---

I also tried to create `SCNScene` another way.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Set the view's delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self
        
        // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true

        // --- Another way to create SCNScene ---
        let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Applications/xcode/Development/ARDicee/ARDicee/art.scnassets/diceCollada.scn")
        do {
            let diceScene = try SCNScene(url: filePath)
            if let diceNode = diceScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Dice", recursively: true) {
                diceNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -0.1)
                sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(diceNode)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

But it gave this error.

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “diceCollada.scn” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Applications/xcode/Development/ARDicee/ARDicee/art.scnassets/diceCollada.scn, NSUnderlyingError=0x282924570 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

---

I'm trying to create a new `SCNScene` from 'diceCollada.scn' file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Resetting the path to command-line tools

There are some issues in your `command line tools`. As a result, the content in the `art.scnassets` folder isn't readable. In order to fix this, you need to install the latest version of `Command_Line_Tools` for Xcode 14.1 and then execute the following commands in Terminal:

```bash
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

---

```bash
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

[image]

### Reinstalling command-line tools

Or you can remove the old version of `command line tools` and install the new one using Terminal:

```bash
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

---

```bash
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Then restart your Mac.

I had the same problem and these steps helped me.

### Renaming

If the above steps still do not help, rename the `art.scnassets` folder to `artisan.scnassets`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I tried this process. I renamed the "art.scnassets" folder to "artisan.scnassets", and my problem was solved.

Comment: congratulations Andy - you are the man

Answer (score 3):

If the app cannot load the spaceship from the apple template, the project might be broken somehow. Try to create a brandnew, default SceneKit/ARKit project, compile it directly and check if the spaceship loads correctly. If yes, copy and paste the code from your current project into the new one. If the spaceship does not even load from a fresh template, your xCode installation could be broken. You can also clean your project build folder or delete derived data, there are articles here on how to do such things. In addition you could share your project here on StackOverflow, so that we can have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I created a brand new SceneKit project. But I still have the same problem.
My Xcode doesn't recognize "ship.scn" file.

Comment: My case solved by installing the command tools 10 above & clean build project. Thanks to your answer ZAY!!

Answer (score 3):

Literally lost a day trying to fix this doing all the above - and anything else I found online - reinstalled XCode, command line tools etc etc nothing worked - BUT the below just worked for me, so posting in case it prevents someone from losing hours like myself:

1. Copy the **contents** of the art.scnassets folder to a safe location on hard drive (e.g. a new folder on desktop) - but NOT include the "art.scnassets" folder, just everything below it.
2. Created a **new "art.scnassets" folder** (Xcode Menu File>New File>Scenekit Catalog> "art.scnassets").
3. Drag and drop (copy) the contents from the safe hard drive location in there, and it worked.

So for some reason the folder itself had been corrupted - for an unknown reason, it worked for 2 years on that app - and renaming it or manipulating its contents did nothing, and recreating a new one solved it.